# Given team size and team member constraints, find all possible team combinations

Tags: java, combinatorics

Find the number of possible combinations given a team size N and two possible teams A and B with constraints on the number of consecutive As and Bs allowed.

Example: N= 4

A constraint: 3

B constraint: 2

A constraint means there must be fewer than 3 consecutive As. B constraint means there must be fewer than 2 consecutive Bs. Team size of 4

Possible combinations:

AABA

BAAB

ABAA

BABA

ABAB

Therefore the program program should return 5.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, the _number_ of combinations, or the _actual_ combinations?

Comment: I tried backtracking but I'm looking for a more efficient solution. It should the number of combinations. @tobias_k

Comment: Did your backtracking solution solve the problem?

Comment: Yes it did I was trying to find a more efficient solution.

Comment: You could use memoization. The number of possible combinations depends only on `n` the number of remaining team members, `t` the last team, and `k` the number how often that team appeared in a row last. This should reduce the complexity greatly as many repeated "paths" can be avoided.

Comment: Show your current approach so we have something to build upon.